# Wrong print in jdom xml parser in java

Tags: java, jdom, println

I have a problem while running the following code

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    File xmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\V\\Documents\\douleia\\temp\\dokimi.xml");

    try {

        Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        List list = rootNode.getChildren("safety_application");



        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

               Element element = (Element) list.get(i);
               System.out.println("number :" + element.getAttributeValue("id"));
               System.out.println("element : " + element.getChildText("element"));
               System.out.println("File_name : " + element.getChildText("name"));  

            }


        }


    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't get any errors but it doesn't print anything. Meaning that the program is supposed to print `number: 1 
          element: element
          File_name: AND`
I get an output like this `[]`

My XML file has this form

```
<safety_application>
<element id="1">
    <name>AND</name>
</element>
<element id="2">
    <name>OR</name>
</element>
</safety_application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root element is "safety_application".
try this:

```
List list = rootNode.getChildren("element");
```